# How can I format/partition a new 1TB hard drive for a PS3?

Tags: ps3

I'm upgrading my PS3's internal hard drive. I have one of the bigger 'fat' models of PS3.

Would cloning would be the best process?

Comment: Uh, could you please rephrase your question so that it is understandable?

Comment: For keeping the backup, third-party software https://www.easeus.com/partition-manager-software/format-external-hard-drive-for-ps3.html# would help you to format the external hard drive for PS3.

Answer (score 2):

The process of upgrading the hard drive for the PS3 and PS4 is basically the same. Turn off system, remove old hard drive, replace with new drive. Turn console back on. The console will automatically tell you to format the drive, you select OK.

If you want to keep your old data, you'll need to use the backup utility before removing the old hard drive and then restore to the new drive.